# SHOW CREATE TABLE outputs TYPE instead of ENGINE

Tags: mysql

I'm running MySQL 5.5. If I execute `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name` (in phpmyadmin or with mysqli in php) the output is

```
CREATE TABLE `table_name` (
 -- rows
) TYPE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2
```

However the `TYPE` keyword is deprecated and removed in MySQL 5.1 and `ENGINE` should be used. Why is MySQL using `TYPE`? Am I missing something here?

If I use the export feature of phpmyadmin the dump will use `ENGINE`.

Edit: The linked question does not answer why `TYPE` is in the output.
Secondly, because it is asked. Here is the version I use.

```
SELECT VERSION();
5.5.17
```

Comment: Are you sure you're running 5.5?

Comment: @aynber No it is not. The other question does not answer why TYPE is used in output. And yes I use 5.5

Comment: Could you run  `SELECT VERSION()` and show us the exactly version of your MySQL?

Comment: Just did it to make sure. It output `5.5.17`